# Запрет на переход на сайт с определенного домена

Tags: php, .htaccess

Сразу к делу - как запретить переход на сайт с другого домена??
Мне нужно избавится от нецелевого трафика.

Пробовал следуещее:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* – [F]
```

И Это

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* – [F]
```

Comment: Что должно происходить, если пользователь попытается зайти на сайт с другого домена?

Comment: @Kosmos deny (то есть 403)